# C# Loop for reverse array that contains most recent 7 data from a dataseries(feed)

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

First of all, Hi everyone and thanks for the Help. This is my first post/question. I'll try to be as straight forward as possible.

```
public override void Calculate(int index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        //..
        if (a_gamma[index] == TAU[index])
        {
            a_gamma_tau_health[i] = a_gamma[index];
            TEST[index] = a_gamma[index];
        }
        //..
    }
}
```

//Output

a_gamma_tau_health

| 71.9 | 71.9 | 71.9 | 71.9 | ...

I need a fix for this for*loop since it will Output the same value in all 7 indexes. And advice how to obtain a reverse of this array that will contains most recent 7 data from the DataSeries(feed) a_gamma - This series either contains double.NaN or double values(which we need to fish out). Hence needing relevant double data inside the array for further assessment.

//info

1. The if condition is placed to find the double values within a_gamma
   through double.NaN indexed void; So if that is True we have a double
   found we need to right down inside the array.
2. TAU and a_gamma are not static DataSeries but constantly updated with new data from right to left (ex. [index-x]).
3. The only way I can read data is trough [index], which I already have in the background. I just need a loop that picks up those values and writes them down into an array.

//Update

I managed to fix the issue and have the 4 most recent data displayed and ready for further operations. It is a manual (if) version of the loop I wanted and I know it's by far the least elegant way to have the code but at least now you can see what I needed. Can anyone present me a more elegant way to do this? I was aiming for a loop and array, but anything more elegant will do. Thank you.

```
public override void Calculate(int index)
    {

        //..
        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int z = 0;
        var Display = 0.0;
        var Display2 = 0.0;
        var Display3 = 0.0;
        var Display4 = 0.0;
        for (int a = 0; a < 700; a++)
        {
            if (a_gamma[index - a] == TAU[index - a])
            {
                if ((x == 0) && (y == 0) && (z == 0))
                {
                    Display = a_gamma[index - a];
                    x++;
                }
                else
                {
                    if ((x != 0) && (y == 0) && (z == 0))
                    {
                        Display2 = a_gamma[index - a];
                        y++;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if ((x != 0) && (y != 0) && (z == 0))
                        {
                            Display3 = a_gamma[index - a];
                            z++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Display4 = a_gamma[index - a];
                            x = 0;
                            y = 0;
                            z = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        //..

    }
```

Comment: Should you be using `i` in instead of `index`, for finding the index of your arrays in your for loop?

Comment: Fix what? What is the expected behavior? And where do you have any output in the example? Also you are only using the iteration variable `i`  in exactly one spot: the assignment, meaning that if your `if` ever evaluates to `true` it will overwrite all the values in the array `a_gamma_tau_health`

Comment: Please write clear questions and avoid bad writing like str8forward. Using such works is a clear lack of effort and not acceptable on a professional site.

Comment: Phil1970 It was a mistake apparently, but with good intent. A little personality in the writing I suppose. Thank you anyway for looking out for this amazing website. I didn't know what to expect. It clearly is SHARP and professional.

Comment: @UnholySheep - you are onto something. Perhaps thats why I get the same value in all 7. How can I work around this or fix it?

Answer (score 1):

while it is difficult to assess without having a bit more of the code, it would appear that you never use your indexer (i) within your loop, and instead use the parameter of your function (index).

Maybe something like this:

```
    public override void Calculate(int index)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
        {
            if (a_gamma[i] == TAU[index])
            {
                a_gamma_tau_health[i] = a_gamma[i];
                TEST[i] = a_gamma[i];
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: It should've worked if my loop would push trough the dataseries 7 values and find what it needs. But the [index] takes care of that and I need the [i] to throw in the values it will find when (if) is true. And i need only the last 7 values. TEST[index] lights up with all the data right but the a_gamma_tau_health is stuck with the last value repeated 7x times.